# Rethrowing Exception without requiring throws Exception?

Tags: java

Consider the following code:

```
static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

[This code compiles](http://ideone.com/ZhH0DZ) without having to add `throws Exception` to the method signature. (It behaves similarly with `Throwable` in place of `Exception`, too).

I understand why it *can* be run safely, in that `Exception` can't actually be thrown in the `try` block, so a checked exception cannot be thrown; I'm interested to know where this behaviour is specified.

It's not simply that the `throw e` is never reached: the following code also compiles:

```
static void stillCompilesWithThrownUncheckedException() {
  try {
    throw new NullPointerException();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

But if you throw a checked exception, it doesn't compile, as I expect:

```
static void doesNotCompileWithThrownCheckedException() {
  try {
    throw new Exception();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;  // error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
  }
}
```

In [JLS Sec 11.2.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.2), it says:

> A `throw` statement (§14.18) whose thrown expression has static type E and is not a final or effectively final exception parameter can throw E or any exception class that the thrown expression can throw.

My interpretation of this statement is that `throw e` can throw `Exception`, because the static type of `e` is `Exception`. And then, in [`JLS Sec 11.2.3`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3):

> It is a compile-time error if a method or constructor body can throw some exception class E when E is a checked exception class and E is not a subclass of some class declared in the throws clause of the method or constructor.

But it's not a compile-time error in the first two cases. Where is this behavior described in the language spec?

---

Edit: having marked it a dupe, I was going to ask the follow-up question: *why isn't `throw e;` considered unreachable in the first example*.

The answer was much easier to find in [JLS Sec 14.21](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21):

> - A catch block C is reachable iff both of the following are true:
>
>   - Either the type of C's parameter is an unchecked exception type or Exception or a superclass of Exception, or some expression or throw statement in the try block is reachable and can throw a checked exception whose type is assignable to the type of C's parameter. (An expression is reachable iff the innermost statement containing it is reachable.)
>
>     See §15.6 for normal and abrupt completion of expressions.
>   - There is no earlier catch block A in the try statement such that the type of C's parameter is the same as or a subclass of the type of A's parameter.

Both of these are true (it's of type `Exception`, and there's no earlier catch block), so it's "reachable". I guess the effort of calling out an empty `try` block as a special case was too great for such a marginally-useful construct.

Comment: When I try to compile the `main` method with the empty `try` block, I get the error `incompatible types: Exception cannot be converted to Throwable`. What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913834/rethrowing-an-exception-why-does-the-method-compile-without-a-throws-clause

Comment: @EliSadoff the demo is on Ideone, so whatever they use. I think it's [sun-jdk-8u51](https://ideone.com/credits).

Comment: @Tunaki related, but that only describes the phenomenon, without actually giving concrete pointers to JLS.

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm running Java 9-ea and it doesn't compile there.

Comment: @Andy Yep, hence only related :).

Comment: I guess the answer is going to be in [JLS Chapter 18](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html). Gulp.

Comment: This was covered at ["Why is throwing a checked exception type allowed in this case?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24981736/978917), but I won't close this as a dupe, because that one is for Java 7 and the details may have changed in Java 8.

Comment: @ruakh yes, that describes it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the very next paragraph of section 11.2.2 answers the question:

> A `throw` statement whose thrown expression is a final or effectively final exception parameter of a `catch` clause C can throw an exception class E iff:
>
> - E is an exception class that the `try` block of the `try` statement which declares C can throw; and
> - …

So, `throw e;` “can throw” only exceptions which the corresponding try-block “can throw,” where the latter is defined by the actual statements in the try-block.

Obviously an empty try-block does not qualify as a “can throw” section for any exception class.  Your second example “can throw” NullPointerException, and since the catch-block “can throw” only the exception that the try-block “can throw,” the catch-block too can throw only the unchecked NullPointerException.

Your third example’s try-block “can throw” java.lang.Exception itself, therefore the catch-block “can throw” java.lang.Exception, so java.lang.Exception must be caught or declared to be thrown.