# Catch (Exception e) in Java in versions earlier than Java 7

Tags: java, exception

In Chapter 3 of the Oracle OCP Java SE 8 Programmer II Study Guide, it says the following (pg. 184):

In Java 6, we can't write `catch (Exception e)` and merely throw specific exceptions.  If we tried, the compiler would still complain:

unhandled exception type `Exception`.

What does this mean?  What is a specific example?

Comment: did u try? `... catch(Exception e) {throw e;}`

Comment: What is the example to try?  It says throw specific exceptions.

Comment: aren't you missing `throws Exception` next to the method declaration?

Comment: `try {
            throw new Exception();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }` specific example - try adding this code to a method.

Comment: The change is also explained in this related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186276/rethrowing-exception-without-requiring-throws-exception (and several others), but in the opposite direction - with assuming knowledge of the previous behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```
Integer add (Integer a, Integer b) {
    try {
        return a + b;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Of course, the addition of two numbers cannot throw any checked exceptions.  However, in Java 6, the compiler sees `throw e`, where `e` is an `Exception`, and concludes that the method can throw any `Exception`.  This requires add to declare that it `throws Exception`.

From Java 7, the compiler is a bit more clever with working out what types of exception `e` can be when it is re-thrown.  In this case, it is able to work out that `e` can only be a `RuntimeException` (which is unchecked), and thus the declaration that add `throws Exception` is no longer necessary.